# Spring Bean Inheritance - Scope, autowire, depends-on, etc

Tags: spring

From Spring documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions:

> The remaining settings are **always  taken from the child definition**: depends on, autowire mode, dependency check, singleton, scope, lazy init.

I think there is a good reason for not inheriting these settings, but can't think of one. What are the reasons?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because it would cause more confusion. Imagine the time spent debugging why your bean is not in the default (singleton) scope. Or the case when the child bean is injected into a bean that the parent `depends-on`. You will get a circular dependency without being able to notice it.

Bean inheritance is only in terms of properties injected, and not in terms of bean settings.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons is that Spring is used to inject implementations. Usually, extended classes are the implementations and it's natural to pick up the configuration details from their definitions.

Other practical reason is that annotations are not inherited. If an interface has annotated methods this annotation is not automatically visible in the implementing/extending classes without some reflection gymnastics.